# Displaying different image using the drop down list (ASP.net MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am currently creating a student database and needing assistance with displaying different image while choosing different options from my drop down list in my login page. The list includes a list of different user types such as students, teacher, parents, principal, admin, etc.

My login.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace LoginQuery
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=CHRIS\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FPSDD;Integrated Security=True";
            con.Open();
        }

        protected void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PersonType FROM Person where Username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "' and PersonType='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "'";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(ds, "Person");
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect(url: "http://localhost:56061/");
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PersonType FROM Person where Username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(ds, "Person");

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Invalid User Type. Please Try Again!";
                }
                else
                {

                    Label1.Text = "Invalid User Type, Username or Password. Please Try Again!";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My login.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="LoginQuery.Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;}
        form {border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;}
        h1 {color: #da2f3f;}

        input.textbox[type=text], input.textbox[type=password] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .mybtn {
            background-color: #da2f3f;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 100%;
        }

        button:hover {
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        .imgcontainer {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
        }

        img.avatar {
            width: 15%;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .container {
            padding: 16px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center";>Login</h1>
    <form runat="server">
        <div class="imgcontainer" style="text-align:center">
            <img src="Images/student.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar" />
        </div>

        <table class="container">
                <tr>
                    <td>Select User Type: </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Button1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="155px">
                        <asp:ListItem>Student</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Teacher</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Counselor</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Parent</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Principal</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Admin</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username: </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<asp:Textbox type="text" ID="txtUsername" placeholder="Enter Username" runat="server"></asp:Textbox></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password: </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox type="password" ID="txtPassword" placeholder="Enter password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<asp:Button class="mybtn" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="BtnLogin_Click"/></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
                   <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label></div>     
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Ultimately, I'd like it look like the following photo below:
[This is the student view when the student in the list item is chosen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbU5I.png)

[This is the student view when the teacher in the list item is chosen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmp5q.png)

Comment: You should handle the SelectedIndexChanged event...

Comment: Are we sure this is an MVC project as per the title?
.aspx would indicate web forms wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on client side using javascript/jquery. Hook a javascript function for OnChange event of dropdown. Something like this https://codepen.io/joshwentz/pen/jEKVoz

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<select onchange="$('#imageToSwap').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="http://cdns2.freepik.com/free-photo/facebook-logo_318-49940.jpg" selected>Facebook</option>
    <option value="http://cdns2.freepik.com/free-photo/twitter-logo_318-40459.jpg">Twitter</option>
    <option value="http://cdns2.freepik.com/free-photo/instagram-social-network-logo-of-photo-camera_318-64651.jpg">Instagram</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<img id="imageToSwap" class="profile" src="http://cdns2.freepik.com/free-photo/facebook-logo_318-49940.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the photos by creating an event in my Login.aspx.cs

```
protected void UserType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/student.png";
            {
                if (userType.SelectedValue == "Student")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/student.png";
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Teacher")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/teacher.png";
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Counselor")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/counselor.png";
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Parent")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/parent.png";
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Principal")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/principal.png";
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Admin")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/admin.png";
                }
                else
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/student.png";
                }
            }
        }
```

In my login.aspx, I created a default image for student as it is the first list in my drop down. I added this AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="UserType_SelectedIndexChanged" to make sure when the certain list is selected, it changes the photo from the event.

```
<div class="imgcontainer" style="text-align:center">
            <asp:Image ID="ImageDef" ImageUrl="Images/student.png" runat="server" class="avatar" />
        </div>

        <table class="container">
                <tr>
                    <td>Select User Type: </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Button1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="userType" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Height="20px" Width="155px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="UserType_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Student">Student</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Teacher">Teacher</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Counselor">Counselor</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Parent">Parent</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Principal">Principal</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Admin">Admin</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
```