# How to take additional variable of choosen object from other table in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a list of persons. Admin can create, edit or remove it. Person.cs in Models

```
namespace Site.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
        public string Image { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
```

Also I have a list of news. News.cs in Models

```
namespace Site.Models
{
    public class News
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; } = "";
        public string Body { get; set; } = "";
        public string Person { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
```

NewsController.cs

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult EditNews(int? id, string[] countries)
        {
            var persons = _repo.GetAllStaff();
            ViewBag.Persons = new SelectList(persons , "Name", "Name");
            if (id == null)
                return View(new News());
            else
            {
                var news= _repo.GetNews((int)id);
                return View(news);
            }
```

EditNews.cs

```
<div>
    <form asp-controller="Panel" asp-action="EditNews" method="post">
        <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />
        <div>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input asp-for="Title" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label asp-for="Person"></label>
            <select asp-for="Person" asp-items="ViewBag.Persons"></select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Body</label>
            <textarea id="editor" asp-for="Body"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

When I create a person I add his name and photo. When I create news I add title, text in body and a person who is author of this. List of persons is downloaded from Persons' table (from previous sentence). I choose the person. I would like that not olny name of person, but also photo of choiced person will be shown in news. How can I do this?

Comment: Your News model's Person is just a string with no constraints? Shouldn't it be a foreign key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment your view has no context of what a Person is, The only thing going to your view is a keyvalue pair of a persons Name.

I'd suggest to start by adding the result of _repo.GetAllStaff(); to the viewbag and go from there.

Take a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005284/displaying-different-image-using-the-drop-down-list-asp-net-mvc)